# Apache POI excel showing cells bold on 10 percent

Tags: apache-poi

ISSUE: 1

I see a very strange behavior of Apache POI, I wrote an excel file using POI 3.9. While writing the cell I added a font style of Arial 8 and normal and the cells are merged.

While viewing the report all the cell styles are fine but I see that the text are bold. When I checked the cell property it looks fine. If in the ms excel I unmerge and again merge the cells the bold goes away but when written from POI it shows as bold.

One thing I found today is it looks bold only when in 100% zoom, even if I make it 99% the bold goes away.

Could anyone please explain this behavior and let me know what I have to do to fix this.

ISSUE 2:

I am adding the copyright symbol to the footer, but for some reason I see a question mark in the footer. Any idea what should I add to get the copyright symbol?

Comment: Could some one please answer any of the questions. I tried my level best to adress them but still struck.

Comment: I figured out these issues, ISSUE 1: When I looked at the API level, I see that all the merge regions are actually stored as a list. So when you remove on merger the list reshuffles it. The issue with my case is the same cell are mergered many times (not sure how). So I found out all of them and removed all the merge annd did a fresh merge again, then the boldness went away

Comment: For the ISSUE 2: To get the copy right symbol correctly in the footer you have to use "&8©" while setting the copyright